# SVN to Git to Gitolite and Lots of Files

Tags: svn, git, gitolite

Ok, so I've read just about every resource possible on converting from SVN to Git. I am attempting to abandon our SVN server completely and move forward with Gitolite, which is already setup and ready to go.

I used svn2git (the ruby script), but ran into some issues that have been documented here on SO. I'm moving about 9gb everytime I run the script, so it's creating some difficulty when troubleshooting. I was finally able to import everything in using `git svn` from the SVN to my local machine, and that's where I'm stuck.

I need to set one of the branches as the master, and then push that to a new gitolite repo - but I'm completely lost on the process. I'd also like to ignore a bunch of the media files that don't need to be tracked in the repo, and I'm lost on that too because (if I understand correctly) I can't use .gitignore on files that have already been tracked.

Any tips, resources, or different methods would be totally appreciated.

Edit: It should be noted that the SVN was being used by a single developer, so blowing out the SVN completely and starting from scratch (with the commit data saved, of course) is not out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of times it's not worth it to import the history. Just manually import the important branches and tags. Refer to the old svn when needed. Been through this twice and would not recommend it to anyone.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. It is a pain!

Comment: You have my full support if you go down that road. But I highly discourage it.

Answer (score 3):

Just recently I wrote a post covering exactly this topic - how to migrate from Svn to Gitolite.

I'm giving a link to my blog, but the post is 100% relevant to the question: http://blog.subgit.com/from-svn-to-gitolite/

In the approach described, SubGit is used instead of git-svn and with SubGit import from Svn directly into Gitolite-managed repository is done in a single step.

I assume that topic starter is already done with migration, but I hope others will benefit from my answer.